# how to update the single value in an array of objet with fetching object in the array by its id and how to fetch a single value from it

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

```
var agentSchema = new Schema({
    datejoined: Date,
     Agent: [{
            name: String,
            phone: String,
            uniqueid: String,
            state: String,
            district: String,
            fleet: String,
            payment: String,
            status: String,
            hint: String
    
        }],})
```

this is my mongoose data base code
i want access the array of object agent by id and update payment status,hit,fleet etc indiviually

```
 Agent.update({ _id: req.query.person_id }).select({ agent: { $elemMatch: { _id: req.query.object_id } } }).then(



    res.redirect('/admin/agentrequest')).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

i triedt to fetch it some how like this but i am not able to update the value

```
                                           <% for (let doc of prods) { %>
                                            <form method="POST" action="/admin/editbus" class="user">
                                             
                                           

               <div class="form-group row">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                                        <label for="status">status</label>

                                                        <input type="text" name="status" class="form-control form-control-user" list="status" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="<%= doc.status %>">
                                                        <datalist id="status">
                                                            <option value="Pending">
                                                            <option value="Accepted">
                                                            <option value="Rejected">
                                                            <option value="Waiting for change">
                                                            <option value="Verifying">
                                                          </datalist>

                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="_id" value="<%= doc._id %>">

                                                <input type="submit" value="change" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block col-sm-12 mb-3 mb-sm-0">

                                                </input>
                                            </form>
                                            <% } %>
                                                <hr>
```

here is my ejs

```
 Agent.update({ 'agent._id': req.body.id }, {
        '$set': {
            'agent.$.phone': req.body.phone,

        }
    }).then(

        res.redirect('/admin/agentrequest')).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

i also tried this way
enter code here

Comment: last query looks good, what are you getting in error? try wrapping function in async and put await before query `await Agent.update(..`

Answer (score 1):

```
 Agent.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.agent_id, bus: { $elemMatch: { _id: req.body.object_id } } }, {
        $set: {
            'agent.$.phone': req.body.phone,
            'agent.$.uniqueid': req.body.registration,
            
        }
    }, // list fields you like to change
    { 'new': true, 'safe': true, 'upsert': true }).then(
```

thank you turvishal but this code works for me